# Suggestion: Single Page application architecture issue

Tags: javascript, html, web, vue.js, single-page-application

I have written a web app (Single Page application) which has only frontend technologies involved (Vuejs) and when I compile it, it will ultimately generate web pages (only HTML and JS). I can run this app anywhere by opening the index page.I am consuming REST API powered by oAuth on this SPA (making direct Ajax call to REST API endpoints).

But the problem is, My lead developer is saying the SPA must be powered by back-end service (Server) for example nodejs, apache. And the backend should make call to the REST APIs not directly Ajax calls from the browser (Frontend JS ajax). My SPA app runs anywhere and works perfectly on browsers even without any server.

My question is, do I really need to *render* and run my SPA using webserver, whats the reasons behind making my SPA (Plain html, js) app server powered??

Also please suggest me, if people simply write app using JS and HTML (pure front end) and upload on the server and point a domain name to that html-js web app which will be consuming remote REST APIs.

Thank you for making my doubts clear in advance.

I have remote REST API provider, suggest me best way to write an SPA to consume that remote APIs.

Comment: So when your app is loaded in the browser is the protocol portion of the URI "file:///"?

Comment: no actually I pointed my html file using apache (httpd) so when I hit the IP, my SPA will load. Just to point the IP to the HTML page (SPA)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you. You run your SPA from a server (local) and are arguing asking if your SPA needs to be server from a server - but the reason you have to run it from apache, as you've discovered is to your CORs limitations can be resolved. You've answer your own question.

Comment: there is no any relation between apache and my SPA. I installed the httpd service which will create `/var/www/html` directory on my linux machine and I simply upload the SPA to html directory.

Comment: As far I understand - the question is: do I need my own backend, or can I just make calls to the REST API (directly from the front-end), am I right ?

Comment: @BeniaminH Yes sir.

Comment: Please see my answer below :)

Comment: based on your answer to BeniaminH, then your answer is "maybe". The problem has to do with the "origin" associated with your App. It is a CORs question and depends upon how the RESTful API is configured.

Comment: Yes correct CORS issue will be there too. Lead was saying the app should not be downloadable and usable from anywhere even if we gonna restrict the origin. I can alrter the origin and submit any request, need to hide the orignal API requests.

Comment: without a "Server serving your App", then the HTML file is loaded with a protocol of "file://", that sets your origin to null and any API calls to a RESTful server that requires CORs will fail. Using your local apache server solves that problem because the origin is "http://localhost:PORT". You can verify this by opening your HTML file from your file browser (file://) protocol.

Comment: Correct if we open the app directly @RandyCasburn

Comment: Would you please suggest be a best SPA architecture to consume remote REST APIs. Or best practice, That would be great sir.

Comment: If you don't need any backend features (like caching etc.) - I would suggest a pure frontend (html+js) app calling REST API directly. If you need any of them - then I would setup a backend between your SPA and REST API endpoints.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to sort of emulate a Desktop application. If that is the case, the way I solve the issue you've presented is by using ElectronJS: https://electronjs.org

Comment: The app has huge customer interaction so that's why lead might want to utilize the backend services of the server and operating system supports.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some reasons to setup a back-end service, for example:

1. Hide REST API endpoints
2. Setup your own caching / throttling / failovers etc. to REST API endpoints
3. Override / control REST API responses / requests

Still, you can use only pure html+js SPA, but adding back-end service gives you additional options, not possible to achieve on front-end.

Comment: And my lead was saying he wants underlying operating system support and components to utilize using that SPA.